# SQL - create multiple rows from a single row

Tags: sql, records

I'm a longtime SAS programmer and we're looking at moving our system from SAS to another platform.  I've only a very basic knowledge of SQL the marketing folks talk about using SQL a lot but I wonder how it might do some things we need done.  For instance, we have files with up to 50 million rows of vaccination records for each vaccine that was administered to a patient.  Some vaccines are actually a combination vaccine that represent 2-4 different types of vaccines.  The type of vaccine is based on the value of CVX.  Using a do-loop it's fairly simple to do this in SAS, but I've no idea of how it might be done in SQL.  It's be safe to assume that we have all the CVX codes in a table with 1 to 4 vaccine types that need to be generated.  But how would you do it in SQL?

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about your schema, but it sounds like you're looking to split multiple columns into rows.  You can use either `CROSS APPLY` or the `UNPIVOT` operator.  Here is an example that takes a contrived test table and splits it into separate rows per key:

```
create table #Test
(
    Test_Key int identity(1,1) primary key clustered,
    Test_A int,
    Test_B int,
    Test_C int
)

declare @n int
set @n = 1
while @n < 10000
begin
    insert into #Test (Test_A, Test_B, Test_C)
    select @n * 5 + 1, @n * 5 + 2, @n * 5 + 3
    set @n = @n + 1
end

select * from #Test

-- this example converts the columns into rows using CROSS APPLY
-- this may be slightly less expensive than the UNPIVOT example below
select
    F_Key,
    F_Value
from #Test
cross apply
(
    values
        (Test_Key, Test_A), -- 1st row is Test_A
        (Test_Key, Test_B), -- 2nd row is Test_B
        (Test_Key, Test_C)  -- 3rd row is Test_C
) as F(F_Key, F_Value)

-- this example converts the columns into rows using the UNPIVOT operator
select
    Test_Key, TestKey
from #Test
unpivot
    (TestKey for Test_Type in (Test_A, Test_B, Test_C)) as C

drop table #Test
```